# In PostgreSQL What is g(i) in: FROM generate_subscripts($1, 1) g(i)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is in the postgres manual:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION mleast(a VARIADIC numeric[]) 
   RETURNS numeric 
AS $$
   SELECT min($1[i]) FROM generate_subscripts($1, 1) g(i);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT mleast(10, -1, 5, 4.4);
```

if I write: ( ommiting g(i) )

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION mleast(a VARIADIC numeric[]) 
   RETURNS numeric 
AS $$
  SELECT min($1[i]) FROM generate_subscripts($1, 1);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;


SELECT mleast(10, -1, 5, 4.4);
```

I receive: Error does not exist the column «i»

What exactly is g(i)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

generate_subscripts is a "set-returning function", which will return multiple rows when you call it.  That's why it's most often put in the FROM clause.

By default, the results from generate_subscripts, which comes built-in with Postgres is anonymous and does automatically have any name to use as a handle in order to refer to it in the rest of the query.  This is what the g(i) is; it's an alias for the table (g) and the column (i) returned by generate_subscripts.  So this expression:

`FROM generate_subscripts($1, 1) g(i)`

means:

> execute the function generate_subscripts and assign its results to a table called "g" with a single column called "i"

or in SQL form:

`CREATE TABLE g ( i integer );`

`INSERT INTO g SELECT * FROM generate_subscripts(some_array, 1);`

`SELECT i FROM g ORDER BY i;`

Without that alias, the SELECT portion of your query has no idea how to reference the results produced by generate_subscripts.

The use of g(i) and gs(i) is a convention in the Postgres world.  "g" or "gs" stands for "generate_series" or "generate_subscripts".  "i" is the traditional programming variable for "iterator".  You can actually use any aliases you want, and I encourage you to use aliases which actually reference what you're trying to do, in order to improve future code maintenance.  For example:

`FROM generate_subscripts( $1, 1 ) as features(feature_no)`

[These functions are detailed in the PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html), and it's also useful to reference the [docs on how to write Set Returning Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-sql.html) (scroll down to 35.4.8. SQL Functions Returning Sets).  Once you write one yourself, it becomes clearer why you need an alias to reference its results.

Comment: Thanks Josh, It's very clear now. Very good explained answer. 
Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

`g(i)` defines the structure of the table (resultset) that is returned by the `generate_series()` function.

It assigns the alias `g` to the resultset with a single column named `i`

Comment: Thanks. I referered to this: what kind of expresion is it?: A call to a know function:generate_subscripts($1, 1) and next a call to unknown function g(i). I read all about the clause FROM  and never find it can have two functions one beside another.

Comment: @fvel: it's neither an "expression" nor a function call. It's an alias that defines the structure of the returned table.